# Horizontal line syncing across multiple charts when hovering with Chart.js in Typescript-react

Tags: chart.js, react-typescript

When hovering over anywhere inside of the chart, I currently am drawing a horizontal line all the way across the chart. I want the ability to be able to sync that across multiple charts on the same page. I am currently doing it with the following code-snippet in my options. I would like for whatever point is being hovered in one chart creating a line, to also have the same hover line across multiple charts. You can see in the image I would be hovering right above the 400 ms mark.

```
const options= {
    onHover:(context:any) => {
        const yAxis = context.y;
        context.chart.clear();
        const ctx = context.chart.ctx;
        
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(45, yAxis);
        ctx.lineTo(10000, yAxis);
        ctx.lineWidth = 1;
        ctx.strokeStyle = 'gray';

        ctx.stroke();

    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this and even make it so it could apply to only certain charts on the page, and even have multiple different groups of synced up charts. The afterEvent sets the X value I want, and the className is set to tell which report group I would like to apply this hover to. If it detects it mousedOut, it sets the x value to 0 and therefore hides it. (Note that I ended up going with a vertical line instead of a horizontal, but the same thing could be done by flipping the x and y values and grabbing e.event.y).

```
const [xVal, setXVal] = useState(0)
const [currentClassName, setCurrentClassName] = useState('')
    
const verticalHover = {
    id:"verticalHover",
    afterEvent: (chart:any, e:any) => {
        if(e.event.type === 'mousemove') {
            setXVal(e.event.x)
            setCurrentClassName(chart.canvas.className)
        }
        else if(e.event.type === 'mouseout') {
            setXVal(0)
            setCurrentClassName(chart.canvas.className)
        }
    },
    afterDraw: (chartInstance: any) => {
        if(xVal !==0 && chartInstance.canvas.className ===currentClassName){
            const ctx = chartInstance.ctx;
                ctx.strokeStyle = "#6f6f6f";
                ctx.lineWidth = 2;
                ctx.beginPath();
                //Hardcoded yValues for now
                ctx.moveTo(xVal, 40);
                ctx.lineTo(xVal,265);
                ctx.stroke();
        }
    }
}

Chart.register(verticalHover);
```